# Vendor folders immediately disappear on creation when running composer install

Tags: composer-php, homestead

If I install a new Laravel project in my Homestead Virtual machine and run "composer install" or "composer update" it creates a vendor folder but immediately removes the folders inside this vendor folder again.

I installed Laravel/ Homestead in a Virtual Box on a Windows 10 machine.
If I open the file explorer while running composer update, I can see the vendor folders been created but then been removed (or deleted) again.
If I install a Laravel project in a folder which isn't mapped with the host machine, there is no problem with the vendor files.

Comment: I bet this is to do with the version of virtual box. Gonna upgrade mine and test

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue.

Let me see if I can answer this for you.

- Vagrant installed
- Virtualbox installed
- Windows 10 machine

Running a virtual machine via vagrant on windows 10 sharing a folder with the virtual machine

Does this sound about right?

I fixed by doing this:

- Delete composer.lock file
- Delete Vendor folder
- Download and install latest virtual box
- Download and install latest vagrant
- After computer reboot load vagrant machine
- Try running composer update then composer install

All good now?